# Hello world alert does not pop-up

Tags: javascript

First html code and my hello world alert does not pop-up. My browser enables javascript and does not block pop-up windows. 
Could anyone help please? Also I should say that I'm typing on a french keyboard...Thanks so much ;)

Here is what I have:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My first page</title>
      <script type=“text/javascript”>
         alert(“Hello world!”);
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: replace `“` with `"` and also `”` with `"`

Comment: As Ankit said check the quotes and also check whether JavaScript is enabled on your browser and  whether popup are allowed on your browser or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have problem with `“”`

Try like this

```
alert("Hello world!");
```

instead of

```
alert(“Hello world!”);
```

Comment: Yes! It works now! Thanks so much, I've tried everything but would have never found that one!